# How to get App Link of an iPhone App

Tags: ios, app-store

I am making an iPhone App in which I need to email the link to that App.

I am not getting how to get that link. Can anyone help me with issue ?

Comment: What do you mean with `App Link`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this mechanism:

For Eg: Headlines App is the name of the app then:

```
http://appstore.com/headlinesapp
```

or

first company name followed by appname

```
http://appstore.com/u2opiamobilepteltd/headlinesapp
```

Replace appname with your appname and company name with yours.

Hope this helps.